# Downloading Google location timeline raw data (red dots)

Tags: google-maps, gps, kml

I downloaded Google location timeline history. However, this data is represented as a polyline with just about a dozen time marks (Figure 2). At the same time when I look at the Google location timeline history in Google Maps, I can see so-called "raw data" represented with red dots, hundreds of them (Figure 1).

How do I download this Google timeline history point data or at least extract more time marks from a polyline of my path I downloaded?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: download as json or use http://geojson.io to create points from your json file and save as kml.

Comment: In case anybody was looking, the way you download the raw KML file is to open the Google Timeline to the desired view and then press the gear button on the bottom of the page. There is the raw KML option.